# Find subnet IP of Android (soft) hotspot

Tags: android

I want my app to create a SoftAP (or have the user start the Hotspot for older Android versions) and broadcast data there.

For instance, say the subnet is defined as 192.168.43.1/24, I want to be able to send to 192.168.43.255.

How can I detect this IP programmatically? I find it very difficult to find information about getting the router IP, the netmask and the client IPs from the [official documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-softap-tethering). Still, if feels like discovering peers is the whole point of using a SoftAP, isn't it?

I tried the following:

```kotlin
val connManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
connManager.allNetworks.forEach { network ->
    val linkProps = connManager.getLinkProperties(network)

    linkProps?.linkAddresses?.forEach { linkAddress ->
        println("linkAddress: ${linkAddress.address}/${linkAddress.prefixLength}")
    }

    println("dhcp server: ${linkProps?.dhcpServerAddress?.hostAddress}")
}
```

But this only seems to show the "active" `Network` (the one that is connected to the Internet).

This one apparently shows all interfaces (at least it shows the hotspot interface), but I don't have a way to know that it is the hotspot:

```kotlin
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().asSequence().forEach { net ->
    net.inetAddresses.asSequence().forEach { addr ->
        println("host addr: ${addr.hostAddress}")
    }
}
```

Also for some reason the [docs](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-softap-tethering) seem to show promising interfaces like `SoftApCallback#onConnectedClientsChanged`, but first I don't see IPs there (just the MAC of the client), and second I can't seem to access it from my code (`wifiManager.registerSoftApCallback` does not seem to exist for me).

Comment: hello. not an expert of network stuff but have you had a look at android wifi state machine, in particular the startTethering method? it looks like ip is always 192.168.43.1  (line 1212 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java    )

Comment: Hmm that may be true for the tethering hotspot, but I am not sure it's true for all device, and I am definitely sure that the SoftAP does not have 192.168.43.1 (tested on different devices, on some it even changes between two reboots of the device)

Comment: I see. And what if you use this? getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).getDhcpInfo().serverAddress   The AP acts as dhcp server, right?

Comment: I don't think this ever gives the softap data. But anyway some devices can run both wifi and softap, so the dhcpInfo then relates to the wifi connection (which is the "main" connection to the internet)... :D